# Access denied when "LOAD DATA" in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I have read access to an HDFS path 'XXX', when I execute some statements like
"LOAD DATA INPATH 'XXX' into table YYY ..."

An error occurs:

> ERROR: AuthorizationException: User 'ZZZ' does not have privileges to
>   access: 'XXX'

Why a "LOAD DATA" statement need more privileges than "READ"?

Comment: Because you could do an Insert overwrite on the table. Did you try declaring the table as external?

Comment: Yes, the table is declared external. Actually I just want copy the data in 'XXX' into my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that the LOAD DATA command physically moves the file from the path you specify in the INPATH to the location specified when creating the table. Now if it has to move the data it need RW permissions on the source folder & hence the error.

Search here for LOAD DATA : [Apache Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted)

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You may already have all the permissions set, yet run into permissions error. This is because a previous change has not been reflected in the metastore, hence you need to run "INVALIDATE METADATA" from IMPALA. (If you use IMPALA)

That will resolve the permission issues.